# When an app is relaunched

Tags: ios, lifecycle

I use voice recognition in my app. Is there a way to notify the user on a relaunch after an initial start that voice recognition is on or can I turn it off on a relaunch? Is there a way to test for a relaunch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various methods to track the application lifecycle. 
You are probably interested in `applicationWillEnterForeground:`

See [here for reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

Comment: Thanks I thought I needed to employ the delegate. Got it working. Thanks for helping.